# DB2 Update statement not working using JDBC

Tags: scala, jdbc

I have a few rows stored in a source table (as defined as `$schema.$sourceTable` in the UPDATE query below). This table has 3 columns: `TABLE_NAME`, `PERMISSION_TAG_COL`, `PT_DEPLOYED`

I have an update statement stored in a string like:

```
var update_PT_Deploy = s"UPDATE $schema.$sourceTable SET PT_DEPLOYED = 'Y' WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$tableName';"
```

My source table does have rows with `TABLE_NAME` as `$tableName` (parameter) as I inserted rows into this table using another function of my program. The default value of PT_DEPLOYED when I inserted the rows was specified as NULL.

I'm trying to execute update using JDBC in the following manner:

```
println(update_PT_Deploy)
val preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(update_PT_Deploy)
val row = preparedStatement.execute()
println(row)
println("row updated in table successfully")
preparedStatement.close()
```

The above piece of code does not throw any exception, but when I query my table in a tool like DBeaver, the NULL value of PT_DEPLOYED does not get updated to Y.

If I execute the same query as mentioned in `update_PT_Deploy` inside DBeaver, the query works and the table updates. I am sure I am following the correct steps..

Comment: Parameters in JDBC are indicated by `?` not `$tableName`. But then obviously you need to call `preparedStatement.setString(...)` to pass the parameter

Comment: I'm using String formatting in Scala. So if $tableName is written, I'm referring to a parameter called tableName. So I'm running a query stored in a string

Comment: The it's pretty useless to use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: When I tried using a `Statement` instead, that too did not work for me

Comment: The usual approach to debug dynamically generated SQL queries is to print the final content of the variable before executing. Then inspect the outcome of the string substitution and run it manually. What happens if you pass the `$tablename` as a real JDBC parameter? By using `TABLE_NAME = ?` inside the string and then `preparedStatement.setString(1, tableName)`

Comment: _The usual approach to debug dynamically generated SQL queries is to print the final content of the variable before executing._ -> Yes I did, the query as such is correct, but when executed using JDBC is not working, but when the same is executed in DBeaver tool, it does the stuff..